# What does the "over 8m fewer people" mean?

Tags: grammar, locative-inversion

I've read a sentence from the *economist*,which is as follows

> Over 8m fewer people are in work than before the pandemic.

I think it looks very strange because why people could be over and fewer at the same time?

So I think the normal order should be like this

> People in work are fewer than before the pandemic,the number of which is over 8m.

But I wonder how to understand this kind of inverted sentence,bacause there is no initial negatives or other signs.

Comment: It's quite idiomatic.

Comment: It's describing a negative change.  The greater the negative change, the larger the number.  Yes, it's clear and idiomatic.

Comment: Fewer people (over 8 million) are in work than before the epidemic.

Comment: PPW - 8,000,000 = PW (where PPW is pre-pandemic workforce and PW is pandemic workforce and the items enumerated are workers).

Comment: Actually what “in work” means is unclear. Are they unemployed or no longer in the work force?

Comment: @Xanne - I think it means employed:  Before the pandemic there were more than 8 million more people employed than there are today.   I.e. We’ve lost over 8 million jobs.

Comment: @Xanne In British usage, maybe elsewhere, if you are in work, you are employed; if you are out of work, you are unemployed.

Comment: In American usage,if you are employed or unemployed (but seeking a job), you are in the labor force. If you do not wish to work or have given up looking for a job, you are not in the labor force.

Answer (score 3):

It means the new value is equal to the old value minus 8,000,000 and further minus an additional positive integer number, X, where X is likely to be significantly smaller than 8,000,000.

The original sentence is unambiguous. The proposed alternative sentence:

> People in work are fewer than before the pandemic, the number of which
> is over 8m.

is ambiguous, as it isn't clear if it refers to the number of people in work, or to the magnitude by which the number of people in work has been reduced.